# updating wso2is 5.0 throwing error

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Try to changed the "**Identity Provider Entity Id**" in management console UI, but without luck by throwing this error "`Error while updating resident Identity Provider information`"

**Any help would be most appreciated.**

Cannot find authenticator : `samlsso`

> TID[-1234] [IS] [2014-11-04 19:27:27,930] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ui.client.IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient} - Cannot find authenticator : samlsso org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531) org.apache.axis2.description.RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation$RobustOutOnlyOperationClient.handleResponse(RobustOutOnlyAxisOperation.java:91) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:445) org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225) org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149) org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.stub.IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderMgtServiceStub.java:2206) org.wso2.carbon.idp.mgt.ui.client.IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient.updateResidentIdP(IdentityProviderMgtServiceClient.java:101) org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dfinish_002dlocal_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.idpmgt.idp_002dmgt_002dedit_002dfinish_002dlocal_jsp:113) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155) org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:605) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:544) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369) org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:1015) org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:700) sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor50.invoke(Unknown Source) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87) org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88) org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82) org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75) org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80) org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_insertAttribute_7(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:603) org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp:335) org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:403) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:492) org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:378) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155) org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362) org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198) org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185) org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419) org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370) org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52) org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128) org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68) javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156) org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936) org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52) org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407) org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004) org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you configure Identity Server forMySQL or any other db? This works with default H2 database. But i found some issue with MySQL script of Identity Server. I think that may be the issue for this.

If you open the  `<IS_HOME>/dbscripts/identity/application-mgt/mysql.sql` file,  you can see following entry

`INSERT INTO IDP_AUTHENTICATOR (TENANT_ID, IDP_ID, NAME) VALUES (-1234, 1, 'saml2sso');`

This must be changed as

`INSERT INTO IDP_AUTHENTICATOR (TENANT_ID, IDP_ID, NAME) VALUES (-1234, 1, 'samlsso');`

It is not `saml2sso` and it must be `samlsso`. if you check `h2.sql` file it is as `samlsso` Therefore no issue with it

I think, you can rerun the script again and resolve this issue.

Comment: yes I'm using mysql and noticed when setup using default H2 db it works fine. Thank you for your help.